# ¿Por que me da error de tipo date a string?

Tags: java

Buen día tengo una duda de por que marca error no me deja convertir el dato en string probé con esto:

```
String fecha_termino;
Calendar fechaInicialcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha_fin = fechaInicialcalendar.getTime();
fecha_termino=format.parse(fecha_fin);
```

Y también probé de esta forma:

```
Date fecha_fin = fechaInicialcalendar.getTime();
fecha_termino=fecha_fin.toString();
format.parse(fecha_termino);
```

En la primera me dice "incompatible Types: Date cannot coverted to String" y en la segunda lo hace String pero no le da el formato "dd/MM/yyyy".
Espero alguien pueda resolver mi duda.

Comment: Y la definición de `fechaInicialcalendar`?? Por otra parte sería bueno que compartas las trazas de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos David,

> En la primera me dice "incompatible Types: Date cannot coverted to String"

Lo que pasa es que el método `parse` se utiliza para convertir una cadena de texto (`String`) a `Date`, no al revés, por lo cuál te resultará en una conversión incompatible. En vez de este método, trata de utilizar el método `format`:

```
fecha_termino = format.format(fecha_fin); // convierte Date a String
```

> en la segunda lo hace String pero no le da el formato "dd/MM/yyyy"

En este caso, lo que pasa es que no estás asignándole ningún tipo de formato, sino que estás convirtiendo tu fecha a una cadena de texto, y luego convirtiéndola de nuevo a una fecha.

Comment: Entiendo veo cual era el problema como me guié de otras preguntas parecidas creí que se podía utilizar para revertir gracias por el dato lo tendre en cuenta @C. Rodriguez

Comment: También es importante que leas la documentación de Java que tienen los métodos cuando los utilices. Si te das cuenta, el método `parse` dice "Convierte (...) una cadena de texto para producir un fecha". Y tú buscabas lo contrario. Saludos.